# Jaydata will object still exist after table drop and rebuild

Tags: javascript, jaydata

Lets say I have two tables task and person.

```
//Create related data
todoDB.Todos.add({ 
    Task: "Your task", 
    Person: new Person({Name: 'Peter'});
});
todoDB.saveChanges();
```

I'm trying to implement a way of keeping all the client and server data in sync.

Lets say I changed the schema of person and need to rebuild that table --> I drop person and rebuild it with the new schema.... re-populate it with data including a person with name=Peter. Will "Your task"'s person attribute still link to that same person, or will that attribute need to be rebuilt. I plan use an id attribute in reality and not name, and Id will be a key value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sync happens only one-way direction, you can use the IDs from the server, but if you create entities on the client and you want to sync back to server, the GUID reference types are the way to go to have the same identifiers on the client and the server without conflicts.

Comment: My sync will be both ways. I use guids already. My question is as to whether if I destroy and rebuild a table.... will an attribute in another table linking to this object (referencial integrity) still be valid after the rebuild?

Comment: Sure! Your server will keep the referential integrity, you will just have additional columns on the client I guess. You can update the question with an original server and client schema and a modified one if you have any particular questions.